# PDO Get last 7 days average count

Tags: php, mysql

So each time a user votes for a user on my site, it gets inserted into a table called 'votes' and it stays there forever, I want to know how I can get the average votes from the last 7 days using PDO in PHP? with MySQL driver.

So I want to get the average votes from the last 7 days for what user. I have tried the below but I am not sure how to get the average, or how it even works.

```
$sql="SELECT count(*) FROM votes WHERE userid= '".$row['id']."' WHERE when >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY;";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    $averageVotes = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Comment: Show your table data ???

Comment: It just has a primary key 'id' a timestamp 'when' and a 'userid' to show what user was voted.

Comment: What do you mean by average votes ? By the above query, you will get the COUNT of the user votes of last 7 days!!!! What is the problem here ?

Comment: I want to know how to get the average amount of votes a user gets PER DAY

Comment: So you don't want an average, but a count per day? You need to use something like a  `GROUP BY DAY(when)` to group by the day.

Comment: I want to get the AVERAGE votes its got for the last 7 days please check this site as an example http://findretros.com/rankings hover over the 2 white rectangles next to the banner image, and the top one shows today's votes, and the bottom one shows average votes last 7 days.

Comment: So, it's the Total of the last 7 days' votes, divided by 7

Comment: So you could do `SELECT COUNT(*)/7 FROM votes WHERE userid= '".$row['id']."' AND when BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()`